# Is OpenCL completely broken for AMD Navi series cards?

Tags: radeon, amdgpu, mesa, opencl, hardware-acceleration

I am on Ubuntu 22.04, and it took me a long time to understand this all, but I think [AMD Navi series cards are completely unsupported for OpenCL,](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/4189) which rules out the possibility of functionality for many useful programs, such as DaVinci Resolve, Blender, hashcat, and crypto miners. I have an RX 5500, a card from 2019, and I think I'm just plain out of luck?

`clinfo` shows me this error (for GPU and my iGPU):

`fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/lib/clc/gfx1012-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory`

`fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/lib/clc/gfx909-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory`

Looks like I can install `libclc-amdgcn` to get that file. But that breaks `libclc-15-dev` which is a requirement for `mesa-opencl-icd`. I've tried many different combinations of upgrading/downgrading packages, there is just no way to have both.

I tried Rusticl (OpenCL implementation written in Rust) via [kisak's mesa ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa), but it seems very unstable. I made a small password-protected zip file to try and crack with hashcat, and it can't even do that. Just crashes. Also crashes pretty early on in the benchmarking process.

I found [a more recent gitlab issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/9715) on Rusticl not working with hashcat where they claim that it's fixed in newer versions of mesa, so naturally I went to [oibaf's ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) to hopefully get better functionality, but apparently Rusticl is not included in this ppa.

So am I just completely out of luck? I thought AMD was supposed to make good cards for Linux, yet I can't even run hashcat.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this topic should be somehow clarified. ;-)

We have here at least two aspects or "problems".

- At first, the old Mesa OpenCL API "**clover**" does not support any
  more recent AMD Radeon hardware (I think anything above GCN4)
  because the underlying **libclc** LLVM library was never updated.
  This was requested several times and there are available also some
  sort of patches but they never got merged. I think this is the
  reason for the above mentioned problems. **Edit**: As of the end of
  January 2024 this seems no longer true. Support for newer class
  Radeon hardware was added to libclc with LLVM MR [#78884](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/pull/78884). Check
  this topic [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44186) for more details.
- And regarding the second, - the solution is to use the new Mesa
  OpenCL API "**rusticl**". Unfortunately it is (as of early 2024) not
  ready because it is still under heavy development and not stable in
  building. Also the requirements regarding rust are changing, they
  have increased recently. As a result, rusticl is in the oibaf PPA
  only available for the upcoming Ubuntu 24.04 LTS variant called
  "Noble". All rusticl support for older Ubuntu versions down to 22.04
  LTS was removed.

There exist regarding newer class Radeon hardware of course also the possibility to install the **ROCm** OpenCL API from AMD. This is true at least for most standard RDNA GPUs. However, certain iGPU models and older GCN5 hardware might be out of luck. For those only the Mesa OpenCL APIs are remaining as an alternative.